# Does closure property pf vector addition and scalar multiplication drives other axioms of vector spaces??

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, axioms

I am new to linear algebra course. I am solving a problem in which a set $V$ is given **which is not a vector space** over field $F$ under the standard operation of addition and scalar multiplication. The problem is to identify which axioms of vector space does $V$ follow and which it doesn't.

My doubt is lets say if set $V$ is not closed under addition, shall I proceed to check other axioms under addition for set $V$ (commutativity, associativity, existence of identity element, existence of inverse) or *other axioms under addition are formed only on the basis of closure property and hence if $V$ is not closed under addition, we can say that it won't follow other axioms under addition*??

Comment: You can for example have $a+b=b+a$ for all $a,b\in V$ even if $a+b\notin V$ as long as addition  is defined *somehow* (i.e. as map $+\colon V\times V\to X$ for some $X\ne V$). Associativity is of course different insofar as also the domain would have to be extended to $X$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Isn't it like that addition and scalar multiplication makes sense on a set V over a field F only if it is closed under it???

Comment: "make sense" yes - and also to show that something is not a vector space, a *single* problem is enough. The purpose of the exercise may be different though. I don't know the exact statements, but if sometimes $a+b$ is $\notin V$ and therefore $(a+b)+c$ is not even defined, yo may want to write that down accordingly (e.g., "associativity of addition fails because $(a+b)+c$ is not even defined in general (per lack of closure)")